# chart connection with MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, charts

I am connecting a chart object in mysql database but getting this error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is the code I used:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim com As MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub btnlaod_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlaod.Click
        con = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=noh_mis"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "Select * From database.students_profile"
            Reader = com.ExecuteReader
            While Reader.Read
                Chart1.Series("Male").Points.AddXY(Reader.GetString("Gender"), Reader.GetString("GradeLevel"))
            End While
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not make a command before using `com.ExecuteReader`. You make a string of sql, but never connect that with your database.

Try adding the below line after building `query` but before `Reader = com.ExecuteReader`:

```
com = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
```